# Time difference column is empty when using SPLUNK query

Tags: splunk

I have two columns start time and finish time in the below format. I need to calculate the total time taken and add the difference as a new column.

Splunk Query used:

```
| rename per_stage_info{}.starttime as starttime, per_stage_info{}.finishtime as finishtime 
| eval st=strptime(starttime, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
| eval ft=strptime(finishtime, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
| table per_stage_info{}.stage_name,starttime,finishtime, ft, st,ft-st
```

starttime   values

```
2021/10/11 08:41:40
2021/10/11 08:48:07
2021/10/11 08:55:09
2021/10/11 08:41:40
```

finishtime values

```
2021/10/11 08:48:00
2021/10/11 08:51:38
2021/10/11 08:55:14
2021/10/11 08:55:14
```

ft after conversion

```
1633942080.000000
1633942298.000000
1633942514.000000
1633942514.000000
```

st after conversion

```
1633941700.000000
1633942087.000000
1633942509.000000
1633941700.000000
```

ft-st column is empty

Why am I not seeing the calculated time difference in ft-st column? I tried multiple other ways but the column is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The `table` command does not perform calculations.  Use `eval` for that.

```
| rename per_stage_info{}.starttime as starttime, per_stage_info{}.finishtime as finishtime 
| eval st=strptime(starttime, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
| eval ft=strptime(finishtime, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S") 
| eval diff=ft-st
| table per_stage_info{}.stage_name,starttime,finishtime, ft, st,diff
```